# Is $\sqrt {2 \sqrt {3 \sqrt {4 \ldots}}}$ a rational number?

Tags: nt.number-theory

How can we determine whether $\sqrt {2 \sqrt {3 \sqrt {4 \ldots}}}$ is rational or not?

Is it transcendental or algebraic?

Comment: You should link to previous related discussion, e.g. [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1260557/264) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/898405/264)

Comment: this very same question has a live bounty by another user on MSE, is it appropriate to just copy it here? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/898405/is-sqrt-2-sqrt-3-sqrt-4-ldots-algebraic-or-transcendental

Comment: Its good to know that someone on the internet has discussed my question a year ago. But they didnt solve it

Comment: I'll just re-post the essence of my comment: There's no sense of posting the same question on two communities which share a large intersection at the same time. The fact that you are an MSE user, and you didn't include links to those posts makes me think that asking this question isn't exactly a scientific interest to you.

Comment: The mathematical question is interesting, which is why so many people have voted it up. However, it should be stated that this seems to be an open question, and there should be links to the other places the question was recently asked. The way this question was presented with no context was poor, and that's why there are so many down votes.

Comment: It should also be mentioned that the asking of open questions at MO is generally discouraged, although perhaps the OP was unaware of this being open at the time of writing. See http://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't think it's relevant any more in light of what has been said in the comments.

Answer (score 15):

So that readers don't have to chase down all the hyperlinks, I'll summarize by saying that your number is the square $\sigma^2$ of the [Somos quadratic recurrence constant](http://oeis.org/A112302) $\sigma$.  As the OEIS entry makes clear, numerous papers have been published about $\sigma$, but they do not comment explicitly on its irrationality, even those papers whose sole purpose is to explain how to quickly compute $\sigma$ to high precision.  It is a plausible inference that the irrationality of $\sigma$ (and of $\sigma^2$) is an open problem.